# My Wordpress theme is not loading Adsense Ads Properly Other themes are working fine

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

recently I changed theme for my wordpress website CodeClick.net after changhing them adsense is not loading properly sometime loading sometime half loading ads. And giving large white space after site footers please help.  theme name is Page Speed & SEO.

i am still searching the problem from last 3 months but i dont know how to fix problem

Adsense ads should be loading correctly website url is [CodeClick.net](https://www.codeclick.net)

Comment: My end it loads fine, check-in incognito mode,may be any of your browser plugin causing any issue.

Comment: Not working i have checked. Please check when ads dont load properly there is huge white space after footers and i dont know why this is happning . please help